# Injectivity of linear maps transcends composition

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

Is the following Proof Correct?

**Theorem.** 
Given that $S_1,S_2,...,S_n$ are *injective* linear maps from $V$ to $V$ such that the product 
$$T=\prod_{j=1}^{n}S_j$$ makes sense prove that $T=\prod_{j=1}^{n}S_j$ is injective.

**Proof.** Let $u_0$ and $v_0$ be arbitrary members of $V$ and assume that $T(u_0)=T(v_0)$, furthermore we may assume without loss of generality the following
$$
\begin{cases}
S_1(u_0) = u_1 & S_1(v_0) = v_1\\
S_2(u_1) = u_2 & S_2(v_1) = v_2\\
S_3(u_2) = u_3 & S_3(v_2) = v_3\\
.\\
.\\
.\\
S_{n-1}(u_{n-2}) = u_{n-1} & S_{n-1}(v_{n-2}) = v_{n-1}\\
S_n(u_{n-1}) = u_n & S_1(v_{n-1}) = v_n
\end{cases}
$$
Now assume for an arbitrary $k\in I=\{2,3,4,...,n\}$ that $S_k(u_{k-1})=S_k(v_{k-1})$ since $S_k$ is *injective* it follows that  $u_{k-1}=v_{k-1}$ but $u_{k-1}=S(u_{k-2})$ and $v_{k-1}=S(v_{k-2})$ thus $S(u_{k-2}) = S(v_{k-2})$ me may therefore conclude that
$$\forall j\in\ I( (S_j(u_{j-1})=S_j(v_{j-1}))\implies(S_{j-1}(u_{j-2})=S_{j-1}(v_{j-2})))\tag{1}$$
we further refine our claim by *hypothetical-syllogism* and conclude from $(1)$ that 
$$(S_n(u_{n-1})=S_n(v_{n-1}))\implies(S_1(u_0)=S_1(v_0))\tag{2}$$
$(2)$ together with the fact that $T(u_0)=T(v_0)$ implies $S_n(u_{n-1})=S_n(v_{n-1})$ it follows that $(S_1(u_0)=S_1(v_0))$ which in turn implies that $u_0=v_0$.

$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine, if a bit excessively complicated.  I think a better idea is a proof by induction.  We can be begin with

> **Claim:** If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are injective, then so is $S_2 S_1$.

Proof of claim: if $u,v$ are arbitrary elements of $V$, then
$$
S_2S_1(u) = S_2S_1 (v) \implies S_2(S_1(u)) = S_2(S_1(v)) \implies\\
S_1(u) = S_1(v) \implies u = v
$$
Now, we prove the desired statement by induction:

**Base case:** For $n=1$, the statement is trivially true

**Inductive step:** Suppose that the statement holds for $n$. Then
$$
\prod_{j=1}^{n+1} S_j =  (S_{n+1})\left(\prod_{j=1}^n S_j\right)
$$
is a product of two injective maps.